# Unable to connect to MySQL on localhost from a Java program on Ubuntu

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Following is the code.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ActivityReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                      System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
              Connection conn = null;
              String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
              String dbName = "jdbctutorial";
              String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
              String userName = "root"; 
              String password = "password";
              try {
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
                  System.out.println("Connected to the database");
                  conn.close();
                  System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
              } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
              }
    }

}
```

I have already added mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar in project from [this url](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).
Mysql service is already running.

```
mysql start/running, process 25326
```

MySQL Connect Example.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:348)
    at c

om.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2391)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2428)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2213)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:797)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at ActivityReader.main(ActivityReader.java:45)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
    ... 15 more
```

Any idea.... ??????

Comment: what is `wait_timeout` from `/etc/mysql/conf/my.cnf` ?

Comment: Is the MySQL server actually listening on port 3306? You can check this with `netstat -lntp`.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann : yeah, Mysql is listening on port 3306.

Comment: it seems a bit strange, but could you try jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/ ?

Comment: @Spaeth : After changing localhost to 127.0.0.1, it worked..  thanks :)

Comment: @NishuTayal: I had the same problem, and the answer I commented bellow helped me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect using `127.0.0.1` instead `localhost`, maybe a clue of what is happening on your system:

> MySQL will try to connect to the unix socket if you tell it to connect
>   to "localhost". If you tell it to connect to 127.0.0.1 you are forcing
>   it to connect to the network socket. So probably you have MySQL
>   configured to only listen to the network socket and not to the file
>   system socket.

https://serverfault.com/questions/295285/mysql-cannot-connect-via-localhost-only-127-0-0-1

Answer (score 0):

try

```
>telnet localhost 3306
```

You are supposed to see some server response similar to

"5.5.19☺(:*b2p`p!☻Ç§4Oph7xxsV5C5mysql_native_password"

Most probably problem will be fixed by replacing hostname with ip, check https://serverfault.com/a/90055

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not specified your db name in your connection URL 
 try this 
 *conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url +"/"+ dbName ,userName,password);* 
 And be sure that you have created the database with same name.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue on a VPS linux server. I solve it by replacing localhost or 127.0.0.1 by the real IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run your code on a Linux Machine or Windows Server.

You can change the server from `'localhost' to specific IP 'xx.xx.xx.xx'`

and it should work fine.